# What's the difference between X509Certificate2's RawData vs Export(X509ContentType.Cert)?

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate

If I have an X509Certificate2 object that represents a public key certificate, what is the semantic difference (if any) between returning its RawData and calling Export(X509ContentType.Cert)?

I did check MSDN docs but I've found very little about what RawData actually returns, let alone how it may differ from the Export function.

Answer (score 2):

They are the same. `Export` is on `X509Certificate`, `RawData` was added on `X509Certificate2` — presumably to look like `X509Extension` (or, rather, `AsnEncodedData`).